# Typeahaed.js not working with WebApi Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use Typeahead.js together with WebApi Controller. It seemed like simple task, but no - there just nothing working, no errors, no warnings, just nothing.
Here is JS part:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#hotel_dest').typeahead({
                name: 'CitySearch',
                minLength: 3,
                highlight: true,
                valueKey: "destination",
                remote: {
                    url: 'http://localhost:63270/api/citysearch?q=%QUERY',
                    filter: function (response) {
                        return response;
                    }
                },
                limit: 10
            });
</script>
```

Here is the pretty simple controller:

```
namespace Booking.Controllers
{
    public class CitySearchController : ApiController
    {
        hotelbedsEntities db = new hotelbedsEntities();
        public class CitySearch
        {
            public string destination { get; set; }
        }
        public IQueryable<CitySearch> GetDestination(string q)
        {
            var a = from b in db.LocalizedDestination
                    join c in db.LocalizedCountryName on b.HBCountryCode equals c.HBCountryCode
                    where b.DestinationRusName.Contains(q)
                    select new CitySearch
                    {
                        destination = b.DestinationRusName + "(" + b.HBDestinationCode + ")" + c.RusCountryName
                    };
            return a.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

The controller returns the correct data as far as I can see, so I do not have idea what is wrong.

Comment: You should return a list of items, or atleast an Enumerable<T>, not a queryable. You can't postpone loading until the query hits the webpage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brunis, thanks for your suggestion, but the problem was on client side. The solution is follow:

```
var citylist = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('destination'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                limit: 10,
                remote: 'http://localhost:63270/api/citysearch?q=%QUERY'
            });
            citylist.initialize();
            $('#hotel_dest').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            },
                {
                    name: 'destination',
                    displayKey: 'destination',
                    source: citylist.ttAdapter()
                }
            );
```